# Android: app manager

Tags: android

Is there way to manage other apps installed on the device. For example block or suspend app for some time or set a password for it launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only by creating your own Home Screen/App Launcher.

Comment: No, there's no way to intercept an application from running. There are alternatives but all would require root and be entirely more complex than just rolling your own home screen.